# callbacks DownloadStringAsync is completed to display information

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a WP7 app which gets website information using `WebClient`'s `DownloadStringAsync` method. The `DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler` parses the text before it gets displayed.

Take for example:

```
foo() {    
    ...
    getAllTheWebsiteInfo()
    ...
    // display the downloaded, parsed text [1]
    ...
}

getAllTheWebsiteInfo() {
    ...
    DownloadStringAsync()
    ...
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that at point `[1]` the text is empty (default value).

Is there a way for `foo()` to know when `DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler` has completed parsing the text so that at that point I can properly display the downloaded, parsed text?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't simply initiate the displaying in the DownloadStringCompleted event handler (besides having problems with dispatching the display method to the UI thread)?

Comment: You can use a locking system, but you lose all the point of having an asynchronous method. Can't you just put the display code in the DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler?

Comment: @KooKiz - In this case a locking system is out of the question due to the windows-phone-7 tag

Comment: @Nuffin - WebClient will take care of the dispatching behavior for you. There is no need to do manual synchonization unless the request is launched from another thread

Comment: @Polity Thanks for pointing that out to me. Learned something again. However, that doesn't change the fact that the OP still needs to elaborate his needs for that synchronous behavior ;)

Comment: @Nuffin, there is no need to dispatch the display method to the UI thread on the DownloadStringCompleted event handler, because that event already is executed in the UI thread (WebClient was designed this way), but I do agree with the rest: you should just update the UI on the event handler...

Comment: @Pedro Lamas: I hadn't though to update the UI in the event handler, but i think you're right - it would seem to be the easiest way. I do all of my web managing in a separate class tho, is there an easy way to reference the main UI?

Comment: @Nuffin: The synchronous problem I'm running into is that the http stuff takes too long, and so I'm displaying the default text. I wouldn't mind if it were to be updated later, but besides manually waiting a few seconds before updating the UI I haven't figured out a good way to update the UI with the correct text. (hope this clarifies some)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the text in your `foo` method, you should just call the method which updates the UI at the end of your event handler, like this:

```
private void OnDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    DoParsingStuff(e); // do parsing stuff - may or may not be in it's own method ;)

    UpdateUI(); // this would contain your code to update the UI,
                // just as the name says
}
```

instead of your approach, which essentially is like this:

```
private void foo()
{
    // ...

    getAllTheWebsiteInfo(); // as shown above

    // ??? waiting stuff ???

    UpdateUI();
}
```